# OpenCL allocating struct on GPU results in garbage

Tags: c++, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I have defined the following struct in C++ host code :

```
    struct __declspec(align(16)) MyNode {
    cl_uchar        mData;
    cl_int3         mPos;
};
```

and in OpenCL :

```
struct  __attribute__((aligned(16))) MyNode {
    uchar mData;
    int3 mPos;
};
```

now from host code Im calling :

```
MyNode node= {0};
node.mPos.x = 1;
node.mPos.y = 2;
node.mPos.z = 3;

cl_mem clnode_mem = clCreateBuffer(
        mOpenCLctx, 
        CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, 
        sizeof(MyNode), 
        &node, 
        &err);

clSetKernelArg(m_kernel_test, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &clnode_mem));
```

then Im calling a test kernel on GPU which is defined as :

```
__kernel void test(__global MyNode* node)
{
    printf("pos = %d,%d,%d\n",
        node->mPos.x,
        node->mPos.y,
        node->mPos.z);
}
```

but what I see as output is `pos = 0,0,0`, and if I remove the `mData` member from host and device struct definitions, then it is printing correctly .
what is going on here ?

I'm building with VS2015 with x64 configuration and running OpenCL 1.2 on an NVIDIA GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Seems likely to be an alignment problem. `int3` probably has 16-byte alignment, whereas the C type `cl_int3` may only have 4-byte alignment. So the kernel would be looking for it at offset 16 whereas the CPU provides it at offset 4.

A good sanity check would be to print the `sizeof(MyNode)` on host and kernel. If those diverge, I suggest trying explicit amounts of padding or alignment annotations for the struct fields.

Answer (score 0):

I can only advise not to use structs in OpenCL, not only because of the alignment and padding issues, but also the memory access will be slower with arrays of structs since usually only one field is accessed at any point in time leaving big holes in the memory caches.

Since this is just a single struct, why not simply make it two arguments to the kernel? I know it's more code but I'm afraid it's only sane way of doing it.